# How to best to replace the text received in my view with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple parts in a view, And in each parts, I would like to replace the key received from the DB by a word.

For this, I use a "switch".

```
   switch ($course->orientation) {
       case 'all':
           echo 'Commun';
           break;
       case '2D':
           echo 'Design graphique';
           break;
       case '3D':
           echo '3D/Vidéo';
           break;
       case 'web':
           echo 'Web';
           break;
```

Here is a part in my view.

```
@foreach($getAllCoursesBloc1 as $key => $course)
<tr class="link-row" data-href="{{ url('cours/'.$course->slug) }}" >
    <td class="program-table__orientation">{{ $course->orientation }}</td>
    <td class="program-table__course">
        <a href="{{ url('cours/'.$course->slug) }}" class="program-table__course__link">
            <span class="program-table__course__name">{{ $course->title }}</span>
        </a>
        <span class="program-table__course__desc">{{ $course->shortdescription }}</span>
    </td>
    <td class="program-table__hour"><span>{{ $course->duration }}</span></td>
    <td class="program-table__ects"><span>{{ $course->ects }}</span></td>
    <td class="program-table__quad"><span>{{ $course->quadrimester }}</span></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

With my solution, I have to put my `switch` in each part, instead of `{{$course-> orientation}}`

How can it be automatic on all parts? I do not know how to do that elsewhere.

Thank you

Comment: You could use the `switch()` in a controller and the controller will pass the "ready data" to the view, is this the way you do it?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Not right, I do not know how to do it

Comment: If this is something that is used application-wide, then it seems like it would be useful to have this in the model or repository.  A method like getOrientation() rather that relying on the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid long `switch case` statments,

You can create an `array` with `key`, `value` pair of all your orientation's like this:

```
$orientations = array('áll' => 'Commun', '2D' => 'Design graphique', '3D' => '3D/Vidéo', 'web' => 'web');//... so on
```

now use in view like this:

```
{{ $orientations[$course->orientation] }}
```